# Firing a click event on a child component

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have been trying to write a test that will ensure that when a marker is clicked (from leaflet) further details will be displayed to the user. The `Marker` component is a child of the `Map` component. To start I am just wanting to see if the `onClick` function is called once when the marker is clicked.

The `Map` component returns the following structure

```
return(
  <LeafletMap>
    <Marker data-testid='marker' onClick={someFunc}/>
    <TileLayer/>
    <Popup/>
  </LeafletMap>
)
```

In my test I attempt to render the `Map` component and find the marker via a `data-testid`:

```
const handleParcelClick = jest.fn()
it('get parcel details upon clicking the marker', () => {
    const {getByTestId}= render(<Map lat={someNumber} lng={someNumber} zoom={14} parcels={fakeParcels} activeParcel={fakeDetails} onParcelClick={handleParcelClick} />) 
    const marker = getByTestId('marker')
    fireEvent.click(marker)
    expect(handleParcelClick).toBeCalledTimes(1)
});
```

When attempting to run I get the following error:

```
      at getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:22:10)
      at args (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:76:13)
      at getByTestId (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:59:17)
      at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/ParcelDetails.test.tsx:58:20)
```

I have attempted using enzyme as well with no success. The `data-testid` in the actual code is unique for each marker, called `marker` above for simplicity. Am I going about this wrong? Should I be testing the `Marker` separately from the `Map` component?

**Update:** I have attempted to use enzyme as a solution; however, I receive the following error when trying to simulate a click

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$k2volvgmsgj' of null
```

There does not seem to be a consistent solution for this error and I am confused as to why I am getting it. I have ensured that `marker` is the component I am wanting to click and that it is not null.

Here is my updated code:

```
it('Loads parcel details on click', ()=> {
    const mockClick = jest.fn();
    const component = mount(<Map lat={n1} lng={n2} zoom={14} parcels={fakeParcels} activeParcel={fakeDetails} onParcelClick={mockClick} />);
    const marker = component.find(Marker).first();
    marker.simulate('click');
    expect(mockClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behaviour via enzyme. Although it is not the best solution - it will do for now. I know shallow rendering is [not the best practice](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering).

Here is a snippet of my solution using `shallow` from `enzyme`:

```
it('Loads parcel details on click', ()=> {
    const onParcelClick = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(<Map lat={n1} lng={n2} zoom={14} parcels={mockParcels} activeParcel={mockDetails} onParcelClick={onParcelClick} />);
    const marker = component.find(Marker).first();
    marker.simulate('click');
    expect(onParcelClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fire a click event on an element in jest is to first find the element using dom selector and then simulate click on it, like this:

```
let element = document.getElementById('your-element-id');
element.simulate('click');
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Well you shouldn't be relying on an id nested within child, if the child changes the id then your test case is broken.